# Get twitter and google+ profile images?

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm integrating my site with OAuth to facebook, twitter and google+

I can get the facebook profile url, but I'm unable to get any images using the provider Id's im getting back from the dotnetoauth providers.

Twitter
provider user id: 126031206
provider user name: RogerAlsing

Google+
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=somecode-alongercode
provider user name: my email

I've seen a few working examples, but they seem to use other IDs than I get here.

Is it possible to get the profile images using any of the above values?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the OpenID method of authenticating yourself to Google, and not the OAuth2 method that they currently suggest. (And if I'm reading correctly, it looks like an older OpenID method, even.)

Current best practice for Google+ authentication to get profile information is documented at https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/ and https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

Answer (score 2):

In particular, for an authenticated user (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/), you can make a people.get API call, using the special keyword "me" instead of an ID. This will return the profile picture as part of a Person resource, including other profile information, as well as the Google+ ID. Also, to understand your Google+ ID, the proper link would be https://plus.google.com/u/0/ID/posts which is the link to your Google+ profile.